# YA Book - Magical kids at camp. Boy shapeshifts into a kitten to get into girl's cabin

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm trying to find a book. I read it when I was younger, 2008-2010ish. All I can remember is that these magical kids were at a camp. One camp leader was named "Ms.Holiday", and at one point a boy shape shifted into a kitten to get into the main girl's cabin.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can remember any other details, including plot points, language, when and where you read this, and so forth. You can then [edit] your question to add them. Also, you might want to add a slightly more descriptive title.